# How to instruct browsers to clear any pages from our site from cache?

Tags: redirects, cache

Our old website on our old host did this...
When you load `www.example.com` it quickly redirects you to `www.example.com/main`.

We actually just setup a hosted shopping cart website.
We updated our registrar's DNS to point to the new hosts `ns1`, `ns2`, and `ns3`. We configured the software on the hosted website to handle `www.example.com`.

However when people go to www.mysite.com it doesn't go to the new site.

I still see the first page load from the old site, and then it quickly redirects `www.example.com/main`.  In our new site we don't have a `/main`.  So I see 404 not found.

Is there somewhere that I can instruct the browser to not use the cached pages?

The reason why I know this is the culprit is that all was solved when I cleared my browser's cache.  However, our customers won't know to do this or would I want them to do this.

**UPDATE**
I worked with the ecommerce hosting site and they did this...and it worked...

- They added a CNAME record that said www.mydomain.com "is and alias of" mydomain.com
- Updated SEO settings in the engine to: "redirect www to no www"

Comment: I'd wait 48 hours because when you change the server that is handling your domain name, there is something I believe is called a propagation delay. During this delay, several computers around the world begin to learn your new computer IP for your domain. Think of it as computers you connect to caching your DNS requests so that pages load very quickly.

Comment: @Mike is right. It takes quite a while for DNS changes to propagate around to all of the Internets DNSs. It could be that the DNS you used has already updated and others have not. It is just a matter of time. As for clearing your cache and it suddenly worked? It is likely just a coincidence. Caches will update when a site updates usually without any issues.

Comment: I don't believe this is a DNS problem.   The users are hitting the new site.   He's asking about eliminating an old redirect away from the home page from cache?

Answer (score 2):

We often tell our clients that a DNS change can take up to 3 days, but that it often doesn't take that long.

You have made changes to your hoster, this has to be updated to their "Nameserver" until it reaches all involved parties. You have a TTL, Time To Live, you can see this as your case. Say your TTL is 8 hours, and someone did a request, they return that result until 8 hours have passed, then they'll check again with your nameserver. Sometimes you're lucky and you get new visitors or the 8 hours have just passed, other times they've just checked and you're gonna have to wait.

Tip for the next time: Set your TTL to 1 hour *before* you switch. This way you tell everyone "Hey, check again in one hour", which means it takes one hour at most for everyone to switch.

At this point, there is little you can do, because every setting you set, will not be viewed until the current cache has expired. If you're talking about a few users, you can try to get them to flush their DNS locally, that often might to the trick.
You might want to add a `/main` to your new website so you can at least catch the visitors and do something with them ("Welcome to our new site, sorry this page doesn't exists, maybe you want *abc*).

**There are some nuances to this, but this is the basic explanation*

Comment: They aren't asking about DNS.   They are asking about clearing cached redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is probably to set a 301 redirect from `www.example.com/main` to `www.example.com` on the new server. It'll take some time for DNS to propagate, but once it does the 301 will be what you want.

This will tell browsers to send users to the new/correct homepage and alleviate the 404 issue for them. It also informs search engines of the new homepage so that they will reflect the correct URL too. Best for users & SEO!